# Add separator between elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding some links within a div by looping through a set of other elements.

The code looks basically like

```
$('.js-section').children().each(function() {
  var initial = $(this).data('initial');
  $(".js-section-navigation").append("<a href='#"+ initial +"'>"+ initial +"</a>" )
});
```

That produces something like `abcd`

Now, how can I add between the characters a separator such as `|` in order to get `a | b | c | d`?

If I simply add the separator at in the append, I end up with `a | b | c | d |` but I don't want the separator after the last character.

Thanks.

Comment: If it's purely for design purposes, use CSS instead. Something like `.js-section-navigation > a:before { content: '|'; padding: 0 5px; }` and use `:first-child` or `:first-of-type` to hide the separator in the first element. If you insist on using JS, you can rely on the first parameter of `each()` that is the index of each element to determine its whether it's the first/last one in the set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly your code has mis-matched quotes, although I assume this is just a typo in the question as your code would not work at all in its current state.

To fix your problem you could `push()` each `<a>` element in to an array, then `join()` them together with the separator when you `append()`, like this:

```
var els = [];
$('.js-section').children().each(function() {
    var initial = $(this).data('initial');
    els.push('<a href="#"' + initial + '">' + initial + '</a>');
}); 
$(".js-section-navigation").append(els.join(' | '));
```

Alternatively you can use the code you currently are and place the divider using CSS, something like this:

```css
.js-section-navigation a {
    display: inline-block; 
    border-right: 1px solid #000; /* amend as needed */
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.js-section-navigation a:last-child {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/kpq5h69c/)

Comment: @macsig No problem, glad to help